# Use node name with arithmetic counter expression

Tags: macros, pstricks, counters

I want to call a PSTricks macro with a node name which involves the result of an arithmetic expression with counters.

Consider the following, not working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\newcounter{mycnt}
\setcounter{mycnt}{2}
\def\nodename#1{%
  A\numexpr\themycnt-#1\relax B}%
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](5,5)
  \pnode(5,5){A1B}
  \psdot(\nodename{1})
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The macro call `\nodename{1}` should evaluate to `A1B` inside the parenthesis of the PSTricks macro. But the above example doesn't work when compiled with `latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf`. It gives the Postscript error

```
Error: /undefined in 2-1\relax
Operand stack:
   --dict:51/400(L)--   N@A\numexpr
```

which shows, that the `\numexpr` is not evaluated but passed verbatim to the Postscript file.

Is it possible to define the macro `\nodename` in such a way, that it works in the above example? This must not affect, how the macro is used, but must work as `\psdot(\nodename{1})`. And the arithmetic expression involves counters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\psdot` expands its argument, but `\numexpr` is not expandable; it expands after `\number` or `\the`. In the context of a `\numexpr` it's better to use `\value{mycnnt}`, that refers to the “abstract” value, instead of `\themycnt` that refers to its representation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\newcounter{mycnt}
\setcounter{mycnt}{2}
\newcommand\nodename[1]{%
  A\the\numexpr\value{mycnt}-#1\relax B}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](5,5)
  \pnode(5,5){A1B}
  \psdot(\nodename{1})
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I always thought, that `\numexpr` itself is expandable, so I was a bit puzzled, that my version didn't work.